# Python calling plot from R script, plot does not stay

Tags: python, r

I am using Python which calls a plot from R. Python issues the Rscript command. Everything works, except that the plot instantly disappears.

I tried several things on the R side:

- `par(ask=TRUE)`
- `Sys.sleep(5)`

`par` does not work this way; it will just ignore it.

With `sleep` the problem is that R will hang the python script for 5 seconds while sleeping, but also that sometimes I want to be able to close the plot immediately: when I do python just keeps waiting until the 5 seconds are over.

Could it be Python related, or is there a solution in R?

Minimum Working Example:

**R:**

foo.R

```
plot(1:10)
Sys.sleep(5)
```

**Python:**

foo.py

```
import os
os.system("Rscript foo.R")
```

Comment: It's because once `Rscript` completes execution, all the things it opened (like the plot window) close with `Rscript`. Unsure as to a workaround, but perhaps someone has one.

Comment: Actually, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301694/running-r-scripts-with-plots) which will pause the script until a key is pressed, or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063165/r-building-a-simple-command-line-plotting-tool-capturing-window-close-events) which will pause the script until the plot window is destroyed (using `tcltk`).

Comment: First one did not work unfortunately, `message` and `invisble` do not help.

Comment: Is it necessary to have the plot stay open while the script is running? Can you just rewrite your plotting code in the R script so it gets saved as an image?

Comment: @Dualinity, the point of the first question I linked was `readLines`, not `message` or `invisible`. `readLines` will wait for user input (on the keyboard) before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [mathematical-coffee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913184/mathematical-coffee) as from the comments and thanks to Dirk for a similar answer in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063165/r-building-a-simple-command-line-plotting-tool-capturing-window-close-events):

```
> library(tcltk)
> tk_messageBox(message="Press a key")
```

Comment: There isn't really any point in replicating answers as new posts -- I suggest you delete this, and maybe even the question which wasn't novel either.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The question comes from another perspective (python), but I guess that then does not matter?